# Looping through lines of floats/int

Tags: c++, beginner, visual-studio

I'm new to programming and started with some tutorials about C++ on YouTube. Now I was wondering how I should continue solving below. It does work but already it has been like a lot of code to write. And I have more *linetype*s to define. So hope someone can point out a better way

```
std::string filepath = "path/to/file.ext";
std::ifstream stream(filepath);
std::string line;
int i = 1; //For debug purpose
while (getline(stream, line))
{
    if (line!= "" && line.at(0) == '0')
    {
        std::cout << "Line "<< i << " type 0: " << line << std::endl;
    } 
    else if (line != "" && line.at(0) == '1')
    {
        std::cout <<  "Line " << i << " type 1: " << line << std::endl;
    }
    else if (line != "" && line.at(0) == '2')
    {
        std::cout << "Line " << i << " type 2: " << line << std::endl;
    }
    else if (line != "" && line.at(0) == '3')
    {
        std::cout << "Line " << i << " type 3: " << line << std::endl;
    }
    else if (line != "" && line.at(0) == '4')
    {
        //Example string: 4 16 -40 0 -20 -40 24 -20 40 24 -20 40 0 -20
        std::cout << "Line " << i << " type 4: " << line << std::endl;
        std::stringstream iss{ LDrawLine };

        float lineType{}, color{}, x1{}, y1{}, z1{}, x2{}, y2{}, z2{}, x3{}, y3{}, z3{}, x4{}, y4{}, z4{};
        iss >> lineType >> color >> x1 >> y1 >> z1 >> x2 >> y2 >> z2 >> x3 >> y3 >> z3 >> x4 >> y4 >> z4;
        //What I could do is make a line like below for every coordinate. The color and the lineType need to be handled different
        //The positions is passed in to the function. Afterwords i need to draw the quads.
        (*positions).push_back(  0.0f); //so else i need to write this code 16 times for this linetype and still have some other line types to go
    }
    else if (line != "" && line.at(0) == '5')
    {
        std::cout << "Line " << i << " type 5: " << line << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Line " << i << " No type" << std::endl;
    }
    i++;
}
```

If anyone could give me some advice on how to handle this or a tutorial which can help me on this. The code does what it needs to do. I only want it more elegant and why less to type.

Comment: Please include the header files that are used by the code and a sample of the input file so that we can provide a better review.

Comment: In general, the more context, the better.

Comment: Almost confident it is *not* important DutchEcho is using *Visual Studio Community 2019* in particular.

Comment: I failed to interpret `I [want it] why less to type`.

Comment: It's not possible to compile your code. What are `LDrawLine` and `positions`? Could you please provide complete working code?

Answer (score 1):

Break some of the functionality into functions. For instance, notice that all line types except for 4 behave similarly. So how about you do:

```
bool isSimpleType(char c) {
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '3') || (c == '5');
}
```

With this, you can now simplify your main loop:

```
for(int i = 1; std::getline(stream, line); ++i)
{
    if (line == "")
        continue;

    const char type = line.front();

    if (isSimpleType(type)) {
        std::cout << "Line " << i << " type " << type << ": " << line << "\n";
    }
    else if (type == '4') {
        // Omitted to reduce clutter
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Line " << i << " No type" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Finally, let us proceed along similar lines to simplify the case of '4'. I'll let you take over from here, but read the inputs to a vector and pass that onto a function that is responsible for verifying if the line is OK and constructing a suitable object from the data then.

Also, instead of relying on "naked values", you could also consider using a `class enum Type { ... }` to define the different line types. I recommend you read more about enums for this.

Comment: While I don't see anything wrong in your answer, you probably won't get any points for it. There are 4 votes to close this question because of missing context. I would have answered it myself otherwise.